# Updating duplicate Flags AND one or more Views blocks on a page on Flag click

Tags: 7, views, ajax, javascript

I have a page where I have several carousel views that can, at times, show the same item/node in each carousel. Such as a most downloaded and a most viewed. I have two different flags (bookmarks and cart) I need to update across the page as well as views blocks that lists out all of the flagged items for each of these.

So as I have been working on just how to do this I have run into some stumbling blocks. First of all I can hook into the flags JS API to initiate this, which is fantastic. I can even identify all of the flags of the type that has been acted upon which apply to the updated flag.

However I have ran into the following problems:

1. When looping through all of the identical items with say the bookmarks flag I don't seem to have a way to differentiate it from the other flags on the page that need to be updated. My concern is that by looping through all of them I will inevitably leave the flag I clicked on in the same state and all of the other duplicate flags on the page in the new state.

   $(document).bind('flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate', function(event, data) {
     //Your code here
   });
2. I want to prevent the flags JS from showing the popup messages on each click such as "item added to bookmarks" and instead pass that to jGrowl. I know how to generate it in jGrowl, I just need to figure out how to capture that message and show it my way.
3. Finally I need to update the related views block on the page when this is done. Say the bookmarks list block.

So what I would like to know is first, how do I deal with updating the same item's flag on multiple places on the page when it has duplicates?
Secondly I want to know how to capture that message and redirect it to my tool (jGrowl).
Lastly is how do I update a view block on a page with AJAX?

I want to do all of the updates without reloading the entire page.

Currently I am running this on Drupal 7 with Views 3 and using Nice Messages to generate system messages in a Growl-like format.

Thanks,
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem. This is how I handled updating duplicate flags on a page:

```
    $(document).bind('flagGlobalAfterLinkUpdate', function(event, data) { 

        if(data.flagStatus == "unflagged"){
            $('.flag-favourite-' + data.contentId + ' a').each(function(){
                if(!$(this).find('a').hasClass('unflagged')){ 
                        ($(this).html(data.link.innerHTML));                            
               }
            });                
        }
        else{

            $('.flag-favourite-' + data.contentId).each(function(){                  
                if(!$(this).find('a').hasClass('flagged')){ 
                        ($(this).html(data.link.innerHTML));                            
               }
            });               

        }
    });
```

change out the term favourite with the machine name of you flag and it should work...

Comment: Lol, I actually resolved my issue back in September, but I completely forgot to post it. I am going to go ahead and give you the credit here since I don't remember my answer and yours looks good.